# Finding a Minimum Equivalent Graph of a Digraph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I'm looking for an implementation preferably in Java of an algorithm for finding a **Minimum Equivalent Graph of a Digraph** (http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321526.321534).

Even better would be an implementation of "Approximating the minimum equivalent digraph" http://cat.inist.fr/?aModele=afficheN&cpsidt=3634076 (requires ACM membership, sorry)
alternative link http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/grant/kry94b.ps (postscript)

Comment: First url requires ACM membership.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried taking a look at java graph algorithms libraries, like [JGraphIT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: Yes, found JGraphIT. But it doesn't have a solution for exactly this problem. It has some algorithms that could be helpful.